# Call a function from external URL

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, url-parameters

I want to call a function I wrote within my Google Apps Script. When I execute a `getJSON` I suppose it'll automatically run my `doGet(e)`.

My Javascript:

```
$.getJSON(https://script.google.com/macros/s/[ID]/exec, function(data){ 
   //code here
});
```

Is there a possible way to call one of my custom functions for example

My Google Apps Script:

```
function getNumberOfFans(e){ 
   //code here
}
```

Do I have to add some kind of extra function parameter to my URL?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

- In either a "stand alone" or bound Apps Script file add a `doGet(e)` function.
- Publish the Apps Script file as a Web App.
- Get the published URL of the Web App.
- Add a search string parameter to the end of the URL.

You can add search string parameters to the URL of the published Wep App.

Here is an example:

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/[ID]/exec?searchStringName=functionOne
```

The search string is at the end of the URL, after `exec`.  You must add a question mark after `exec` and then `name=value`

```
url/exec?name=value
```

Where `name` and `value` will be replaced with your choices.

Put the event argument (denoted by the letter "e") into the `doGet(e)` function, not the function you want used.

```
function doGet(e) {
  var passedString,whatToReturn;

  passedString = e.parameter.searchStringName;
  if (passedString === 'functionOne') {
    whatToReturn = functionOne();  //Run function One
  };

  return ContentService.createTextOutput(whatToReturn);
};

function functionOne() {
  var something;

  //. . . . Code;
  something = code here;
  return something;
};
```

The above code is for a GET request.  If you want to use a POST request, don't use a search string in the URL.  For a POST request, you will send information in the payload.  You'll still use `e.parameter` to access the data sent, but whatever is in `e.parameter` will be an object with key/value pairs.  You'll need to know what the key (property) name is that was sent in the object.

For an explanation on URL Parameters, see this documentation:

[URL Parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#url_parameters)

Comment: Nice one - I'm favoriting it!

Comment: I got always error message: 401_client_error for a POST call, and cannot find a case online to show how that doPost works. Any idea? thanks.

Comment: You may need to post a question with the details of how you make the POST request, and the `doPost(e)` function that you are using.

Comment: @Albert: maybe it's because you were testing with a Rest client like Postman? It doesn't work with Postman in my case also. But when I tried using a normal <form >, it worked as expected