# Send data from HTML form to Google Forms

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, google-forms

I know some people have asked this question before, but I was unable to find any pertaining to my specific case and/or the responses were unhelpful and the question wasn't answered.

I am wondering if there is any way to have an HTML form (which could use PHP, JavaScript, etc. except AJAX, as I do not know it) post data to a Google Forms form. I researched and could not find applicable ways to do this in my situation.

I believe that Google Forms has a better interface and would rather not set up a MySQL database to handle the responses. Any responses would be greatly appreciated, and I hope this is not too vast of a question. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can make an HTTPS GET or POST request to a Stand Alone Apps Script Web App.  Create an Apps Script file that is *NOT* "bound" to a Google document.  Then publish it as a web app.  Use either a `doGet(e)` or `doPost(e)` function as the receiving function of the HTTPS request.  The `doGet(e)` or `doPost(e)` function will run, and then you can use any Apps Script service.  The `FormApp` class can save data into a Google Form.  So, you can do this with PHP.  It will be a server to server interaction.  [See this link at SO for more info](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30127428/2946873)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that you can embed google forms into websites after looking around for a bit, I was unable to find an embed option in the new google forms.

I presume it would be possible to post data from your own form into google forms' forms, but to be honest why would you? UNLESS: You are thinking of using this as a login... the short answer is NO.

Google forms does not allow querying, so it would be useless anyway. You would have no way of looking up usernames and passwords.

Plus right under the submit button of all google forms is this message:

[image: Never submit passwords]

However if you just want it for data / statistics / reviews or things like that you can always use the built in embed feature! Here is how:

I was forced to click the little stick figure in the bottom right corner of the screen, to revert to the old google forms:

[image: Revert to old google forms]

From here you can go to `File` > `Embed`:

[image: File > embed]

Which opens a window that allows you to choose the size of the form, and copy the code to put onto your website:

[image: Get Code / choose height / width]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did not think it was possible, so I suppose I'll just embed it. As for why I wanted it, no I was not going to use it as a login, but rather I simply disliked the "Google Forms" branding. I may take the time to code a custom form with a database, but anyway thanks for the answer!

Comment: No problem! Thank you for accepting my answer! I have one more request however. If you think my answer was a quality post, please consider also pressing the up arrow next to my question. This gives me extra reputation on the site which is greatly appreciated! Please do not feel pressured however, please only do so if you think I deserve it! Have a great day. Thanks again, Trevor    @Drenagem

Answer (score 1):

## NEW FORMS SUPPORT THE BUILD-IN EMBED FEATURE

@trevor-clarke and @drenagem

> I was forced to click the little stick figure in the bottom right
> corner of the screen, to revert to the old google forms

Actually you do NOT need to go to the old forms.

All you have to do is go to SEND and click on the  `< >` (embed) sign.

Please have a look at the attached images.

[SEND FORM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nonsq.jpg)

[EMBED FORM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4G8W.jpg)

***PS:** The attached images do NOT show up because I lack of rep points.

What to do when someone answers your question ([accepting and/or upvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)).*

Comment: Yes, I found that already. Thanks! (I am very new to this site, so I don't even have enough rep points to upvote.. seriously)

Comment: @drenagem _"I am very new to this site..."_ You should also keep in mind that: 
_"You may **change which answer is accepted**, or simply un-accept the answer, at **any time**.
Accepting an answer is not mandatory; do not feel compelled to accept the first answer you receive. Wait until you receive an answer that answers your question well. "_

Comment: About upvoting: _"Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, **your votes** will change the publicly displayed post score."_ Just try it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the google chrome extension "xpath helper" to pull the data generated from your html form into a google spreadsheet using the function =importxml(