# how to call a google app script function from python

Tags: python, google-apps-script

On a server, I have a cron job which calls a python script. I want the python script to be able to call a google app script function, which performs some actions on a google spreadsheet.

Is it possible to call a google app script from python and also get notified when it finishes?

Comment: I'm not sure about what happens on the python side, but you can call an Apps Script project over the internet with either a GET or PUT HTTPS Request, and have Apps Script return something.  So, make a GET or PUT request from python to the Published URL of an Apps Script Web App.  Apps Script has two reserved function names called `doGet()` and `doPost()`.  If those function names exist, they monitor for an event.  The event being a GET or POST request to the published URL of the Web App.

Comment: Also see:  [Link to Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30126787/call-a-custom-gas-function-from-external-url)

Comment: How about any api (app script api)? Specially I don't want to publish my app script to public. So something like an oauth authorization and then calling an api was in my mind.

Comment: There is no Apps Script API.  If the Apps Script Web App is published to run as YOU, then you'll need to go through the OAuth anyway.  You can create a separate stand alone Apps Script project, just for that one process, and never show the URL to anyone.